# How much costs twilio or firebase sms sending?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, notifications, twilio

I was using **Twilio** for user authentication by phone number, all was fine.

And suddenly my spending is started to *grow up*.

For **usa** the cost for **1sms is 0.007$**, but i launched my app only in certain country, in kyrgyzstan.

Later i realized that the cost is for **1sms is 0.1$** in **kyrgyzstan**. 
So even in a testing period i spent 30$ which is not small.

And by the way, if 100k users would download, that would cost me nearly 10k $.

I am new, have no experience, was using twilio api. And is there any other solution, how much does it costs in firebase? was trying to google, not found anything.

Maybe there are other services which is cheaper, or maybe more better. There is a lot of apps which uses sms authentication, and i wanted to know how they deal with this?

Which sms sending service is mostly used, if there is an app developers, please advice!!!

Comment: You should contact with Firebase, It's hard to calculate exactly which plan you are planning to choose

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns third-party product pricing and support, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746), and [the Help Center page regarding appropriate topics for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Tologon Which service are you using for top verification. Even I'm stuck in choosing between Twilio and Firebase or any other which is cheap and reliable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how much does it costs in firebase?

According to the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) the cost for Authentication is:

> Authentication
>
> Phone Auth - US, Canada, and India
>
> - 10k/month free, then $0.01/verification
>
> Phone Auth - All other countries help
>
> - 10k/month free, then $0.06/verification
>
> Other Authentication services
>
> - Free

So it sounds like for your usage it'd be $0.06 per verification, with the first 10k per month being free.